# Google Scripts - getNumCells Return Value (get number of columns in each row)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

In this basic example I am trying to see how many columns are in each row in a table that is found in a google document.

```
  tables.forEach(function(table) {
  var numberOfRows = table.getNumRows();
  console.log("New Table with Rows: " + numberOfRows);
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++) {
    var row = table.getRow(rowIndex);
    console.log("row: " + rowIndex + " with num of cells: " + row.getNumCells());
  }
  })
```

Here is what my table looks like as a test.
[image]

This is the output of my code snipped

```
New Table with Rows: 6
row: 0 with num of cells: 4
row: 1 with num of cells: 4
row: 2 with num of cells: 4
row: 3 with num of cells: 4
row: 4 with num of cells: 4
row: 5 with num of cells: 4
```

I was expecting it to output num of cells to be the number of columns in each specific row. What am I missing? It seems getNumCells returns the max number of columns throughout the whole table. How do I figure out how many columns are in each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about using the method of `getColSpan()` of Class TableCell? When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
tables.forEach(function(table) {
  var numberOfRows = table.getNumRows();
  console.log("New Table with Rows: " + numberOfRows);
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++) {
    var row = table.getRow(rowIndex);
    var nCol = 0;
    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < row.getNumCells(); colIndex++) {
      nCol += row.getCell(colIndex).getColSpan() == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }
    console.log("row: " + rowIndex + " with num of cells: " + nCol);
  }
});
```

#### Reference:

- [getColSpan()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#getcolspan)

Comment: I don’t think O(n) is necessary if colSpan is the number of cells the column spans. +1 anyway

Comment: @Adelin Thank you for your comment. Yes. Also I think that `if (row.getCell(colIndex).getColSpan() > 0) nCol++;` can be also used instead of `nCol += row.getCell(colIndex).getColSpan() == 0 ? 0 : 1;` as you mentioned. If my understanding for your comment is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike that is perfect. Thank you for the help. I did not properly use getColSpan when I was messing around with that!!

Comment: @Sliffcak Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike if possible can you also show how to edit a specific row,col in a table where the rows have different number of columns. when I do table.getCell(row,colIndex).setText("...") it does not function as expected.

Or when I do row.getCell(colIndex).setText("...") it only works for one col.

Comment: @Sliffcak I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: @Tanaike very true. I created a new question! Thank you again

Comment: @Sliffcak Thank you for your resonse. I would like to check it!